# How to specify each index number - Python

Tags: python

I'm writing this program that is supposed to convert binary to hex. I have to use the for loop. The part I need is how do I get the program to get the integer and its index number.

my code so far

```
q = raw_input('asdf ')
p = list(q)
t = [int(x) for x in p]
for i in t:
    if i == 1:
    w=i*(2**(3-t[x]))
    print w
```

the t[x] part is supposed to be the index number. So what is happening is if its a one then it will multiply by 2^3-(its index number)

How do I refer to the index number?

And how do I get it to sum all the values it gets

Comment: If this is homework please tag it as such, otherwise there's absoluely no reason to code this yourself

Comment: didnt know they had a homework tag will do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ind in range(len(t)):
  i = t[ind]
  ...
```

Then i is the variable you had before, and ind is the loop number.

For the sum, do:

```
result = 0
```

before the loop, and

```
  result += w
```

inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `enumerate` function.

```
for rank, item in enumerate(my_list):
   # here you have the index of the item (rank)
   # and the item ( the same as my_list[rank] )
```

for your example you can do something like this :

```
 inital_binary = raw_input("polop")
 for rank, letter in enumerate(inital_binary):
    print int(letter) * 2**(len(inital_binary) - (rank+1))
```

that will give for an input of `1100` :

```
8
4
0
0
```

Comment: so instead of t[x] i put rank

Comment: @tyim : yes, it sounds like this

Comment: i need it so that when i grabs the i it also knows what index number the i is so that it plug into the formula right each time

Comment: if i use your code i gives me eight different numbers even though i only put in 4 numbers

Comment: @tyim : maybe i didn't understand exactly what you want -_- could you give an example of what you want to achieve (input and expected result)

Comment: if I input 1100 then the code should give me 8 and 4 i work in your code it gives me 8 4 8 4 8 4 8 4

Comment: i did this
     q = raw_input('asdf ')
     p = list(q)
     t = [int(x) for x in p]
     for i in t:
         for rank, item in enumerate(t):
             if item == 1:
                 w = item*(2**(3-rank))
                 print w